# Is it bad style to use 'return' to break a for loop in Java?

Tags: java

I'm doing a project with basic Java for a CS class. The project has a for loop nested inside a while loop.

I am **not allowed** to use `break` as a way of ending a for loop early. I found out that `return` seems to have the same effect as `break`. Is it bad style to use `return` as a way to break the loop?

My for loop has to check through three different statements but if it finds one that is true then it is supposed to end straight away without continuing to check the rest of the statements.

I tried to put a boolean operator in the while loop that controls the for loop but that doesn't control what goes on inside the for loop until the for loop gets to the end.

Also does it matter if `return` doesn't return anything?

299/01/11
Update: Thanks everyone so much for your comments. I found it really helpful to read through all the debates.

I spoke to my tutor and it turns out for the purposes of getting full marks, I shouldn't use `return` either.

So I found the advice about setting a boolean in the 'for' loop really helpful, as I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: I wonder what's the convoluted reasoning behind not allowing to use `break`.

Comment: Add a flag to your while condition.

Comment: @andri since this is a basic Java class I completely see (and agree) with why break is banned. If not then chances are half the answers will just be horrible while(true) loops with break statements in them...

Comment: Not returning anything is perfectly valid, that is called a void return and its intended to end the execution of a method.

Comment: @berry120 Wouldn't it be better to show how not to use and when it's appropriate?  Banning it has given the impression to a classroom full of students that `break` is bad style.

Comment: @Jonathon in an ideal world, yes. But realistically in education there's only a certain amount that you can cover before things get confusing, and just having a blanket rule not to use break removes this element of confusion. There's nothing wrong with revisiting it later and giving examples of when and where it would be appropriate, but that's a relatively advanced topic if students are just being shown how to use loops for the first time!

Comment: @berry120 it sounds like it is much more confusing when you are using something for the first time and are given a task which requires a feature of the thing that you are arbitrarily not allowed to use ... He is on here asking how to not use the proper tool for the job. In an early cs class I think getting it working is top priority. In later classes you can worry about the quality of the code.

Comment: @grinch It sounds like `break` is not *required* at all for the code to work, it's just one way of completing the problem (that would in this case lead to bad style.) And afraid I completely disagree that "just getting it working" is top priority - I think encouraging good quality, well commented code from the outset is of paramount importance. Bad habits (coding ones included) are easily formed, and hard to break.

Comment: @berry120 I agree to disagree ;). I think getting in there and playing with features - and probably getting burned by them - is much more fun and a better way to learn. "I don't use feature x in some situation because my professor told me never to do so, and so i never even really considered it or played with it." versus "I don't use feature x in some situation because when I was working on project A it made it hard to do this one thing later on when the requirements changed". School is about learning; using break incorrectly in your first cs class won't necessarily make you a bad programmer.

Answer (score 18):

They'll only be equivalent if the first thing after breaking out of the loop is a `return` statement.

In any case, if your lecturer doesn't allow `break`, they probably won't allow `return` either.

You should be aware that these rules have a good basis behind them (to prevent spaghetti code and make it easier to write maintainable code) but sometimes they're enforced over-zealously.

For example, there's *nothing* unreadable about the segment:

```
if (x == 0)
    return 0;
return x - 1;
```

even though it has multiple `return` statements.

The supposedly preferred solution to the no-multiple-return crowd is something like:

```
int y = x - 1;
if (x == 0)
    y = 0;
return y;
```

which is, in my opinion, both less readable and a waste of space.

The real problems occur when you have very complex logic and the hoops that people jump through to avoid `break` and/or `return` leads to conditionals that are darn-near unreadable.

Listen to your lecturer - they are, after all, the ones in control of what grade you get. Then, once you get into the real world, you can switch from dogmatism to pragmatism and make up your own mind.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216359/break-statements-in-the-real-world/216375#216375) for some good advice regarding these issues outside of educational institutions.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation, although I think that enforcing such rules in school (while starting to learn) might help. I.e., when people can't use some tool sensibly yet, it's better to not use it at all.  (I was talking about a `break`: I see no way how you can 'overuse' `return`)

Comment: Not being able to use a tool sensibly yet is a result of a lack of experience. The code you hand-in in school isn't going to be useful for anything except your own learning, so you may as well get the most bang for your buck and use and abuse as many features as you can and hence discover first hand what's a bad idea. Up with guidance, down with dogmatism!

Comment: the problem can be solved at the language level too.  For example people liked to be "pragmatic" about the indent (4 or 8 spaces, whatever) and about where to put braces (on a new line or not)... Then designers like the ones behind Google's "Go" language came up with mandatory indent and brace location **in the language specs**.  No more arguing, no more *"dogmatism vs pragmatism"*.  It's defined in the spec.  A language could conceivably mandate one and only one return statement and poof, so much for *dogmatism vs pragmatism"* :)

Comment: @Whisty Sadly, the approach "let's write the worst code possible" rarely pays off in teaching. And beginners rarely can see the difference between good code and bad code. You have no idea how hard it is to explain to 13-year olds the benefit of consistent indentation. The only way is to enforce it. Then, after few weeks/months, they'll see the benefit.  And it's true for most areas of learning, not only for programming.

Comment: @Nikita, I see your point. I suppose it's the wording of "when people can't use some tool sensibly yet, it's better to not use it at all" that I don't agree with. I can't learn how to use something sensibly without using it.

Comment: @E.M. I agree. Once the 13 year old has to go back and read some really poor, inconsistently indented, code that they wrote a while back they will have truly learned the lesson. I think these lessons hit harder and make much more sense when you see them first hand. What better place to make and learn from mistakes than at a school ...

Answer (score 7):

First of all, it's **not** a bad style to use `break`, if you use it judiciously.
Although I understand why your professor insists on coding without `break` for now (because so many people, especially beginners, tend to 'overuse' it), there's no reason to ban it **completely**.

*Is it bad style to use return as a way to break the loop?*
Personally, I think you'll be fine: code will get only simpler. But obviously your professor is the higher authority here. The whole question is very subjective, thus I can't tell for him.

But again, regardless of what your professor sais, using `return` in a loop is **not** a bad style.

Answer (score 5):

This question seems to enter the territory of a very old still unresolved argument, the "**Single vs. Multiple method exit points**".

So if using return in a loop is worrying you (or your teacher), you (or he) could have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701686/why-should-methods-have-a-single-entry-and-exit-points/1701721#1701721).

To answer your question.
In my (and not only my) opinion using a return in a loop is definitely OK.

Do note however that overusing it might decrease code readability (see linked answer for details/examples).

Comment: Sadly, this link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

> Also does it matter if 'return'
>   doesn't return anything?

That depends on your method's return type. if the return type is void, a return clause must be empty:

```
return;
```

otherwise, a return clause must return the required type, e.g.

```
return true; // legal for boolean return type
return null; // legal for all object types
return "Hello"; // legal if return type is String
```

Answer (score 3):

This is about perfect code.

```
for(int i; i < stop; i++) {
 boolean flag = true;

 while(flag && condition) {
  //some action 
  if(shouldIstop) {
     flag = false;
  }
 }
}
```

When you set the flag to false then you will exit from the while, when you will set i to stop then you also will exit from for.

Answer (score 3):

From a purist viewpoint, break arguably shouldn't be used. The point of a while loop is that you use the condition at the start of the loop to break out of it, and things can potentially get confusing if you start to flood your loop with break statements as oppose to getting the condition correct (which is a quick hack students may well be tempted to use if they can't work out how to do things the proper way!) The same goes for continue and returning in the middle of loops.

All these language features are there for a reason and yes, sometimes they're the best way of doing things. When just starting off however, the chances of you using them judiciously and properly are rare, they're more likely to be used as free "hack to get me out of jail without understanding how this thing works" cards. And that, I'd say, is a good enough reason to ban their use in basic programming courses.

Answer (score 2):

`break` and `return` are not the same. `break` will halt the execution of the inner-most loop, `return` will return from the current method - ie nothing more in the method will be executed. As far as I know there's nothing wrong with using break in a loop; presumably this is an artificial requirement in order to get you to think of alternative logic. And there's nothing wrong with using a `return` either; this will save you from horrible nested conditionals (`if` clauses).

Answer (score 2):

*If* you are not allowed to use `break`, then it makes sense not to use `return` as well, since every loop with `break` can be rewritten as a loop with `return` (by outsourcing it into a separate function).

From a non-homework point of view, `break` (and `return`) are very useful language features which are usually *not* considered bad style (of course, every language construct can be abused to write bad code).

In your homework scenario, however, I guess it would defeat the point of the homework to just "workaround" the missing `break` by using `return`. You should think of an alternative way to solve your task.

> I tried to put a boolean operator in the while loop that controls the for loop but that doesn't control what goes on inside the for loop until the for loop gets to the end.

That's true, but, by using the `if` statement, you can also execute/not execute code *inside* the loop depending on your boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You can early-terminate a for loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < SOMELIMIT && (!found); ++i) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine that your tutor wanted that you use the break condition in the condition part of the for loop. You need to declare this condition before the loop and change it inside the loop.

```
boolean stop = false;

for (...; ... && !stop; ...) {
    ...
    if (...) {
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get the same result but the code quality and legibility will decrease.