# When I pass an ArrayList's get method a variable, it's using the whole ArrayList

Tags: java, variables, arraylist, methods

For some reason, when I pass my ArrayList (which is a basic ArrayList from Java's Lang.*) an int variable, instead of taking the item at the index of the variable's int (eg:  `i = 0; arrayList.get(i);`  should be the first item in the ArrayList) - it calls the  **WHOLE**  list.

Here's the method in question:

```
public ZipCode findZip (int zip) {
    ZipCode aZip = new ZipCode(00000);
     //System.out.println(zips.get(0)); here gives 99501,ANCHORAGE,AK
     //System.out.println(zips.get(0).getZipCode()); here gives 99501
        for(int i = 0; i < zips.size(); i++) {
            if(zips.get(i).getZipCode() == zip)
                aZip = zips.get(i);
              //System.out.print(aZip); here gives the zip codes from the whole array
            else
                aZip = null;
        }
    return aZip;
    //Therefore, aZip is ALWAYS null. Even if it exists.
}
```

I've tried a bunch of troubleshooting to figure it out. So far, I've learned that the issue doesn't arise when I put a straight integer in (eg:  `arrayList.get(1);`  gets the second item as normal). There's no compiler error to show, unfortunately.

It always gives me  `null`  when it runs. 
I need to use an int so I can increment it to run through the list, also unfortunate. 
Larger Clip of Program: (Same as from my prior question)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class ZipCodeDatabase {
   //Field
    private ArrayList<ZipCode> zips;

   //Constructor
   public ZipCodeDatabase () {
      zips = new ArrayList<ZipCode> (); 
   }

   //Mutator Method
   public void readZipCodeData(String filename) {
      Scanner inFS = null; 
      FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
      try{
       // open the File and set delimiters
         fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
         inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
         inFS.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");
       // continue while there is more data to read
         while(inFS.hasNext()) {
            //read in all input
            int aZip = inFS.nextInt();
            String aCity = inFS.next();
            String aState = inFS.next();
            double aLat = inFS.nextDouble();
            double aLon = inFS.nextDouble();
            //Create and add new zipcode
            ZipCode newZip = new ZipCode(aZip, aCity, aState, aLat, aLon);
            zips.add(newZip);
         }
         fileByteStream.close();
         // Could not find file
         }catch(FileNotFoundException error1) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read the data file: " + filename);
          // error while reading the file                      
         }catch(IOException error2) {
             System.out.println("Oops! Error related to: " + filename);
      }        
   }

   //Accessor Methods
   public ZipCode findZip (int zip) {
      ZipCode aZip = new ZipCode(00000);
      for(int i = 0; i < zips.size(); i++) {
          if(zips.get(i).getZipCode() == zip)
            aZip = zips.get(i);
         else
            aZip = null;
      }
      return aZip;
   }
```

Here's the getZipCode() method (it returns the zip code int, a part of a small collection of ints including latitude and longitude; of which I have an array):

```
public int getZipCode () {
       return zipCode;
}
```

Comment: What is `zips`? Can you show a complete example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Why do you have `else aZip = null`?  That _will_ change `aZip` to refer to `null` even if a match was found earlier in the loop.  I don't think you want that `else` statement at all.

Comment: Shows us the code from `zips` and ZipCode class.

Comment: what is the return type of `getZipCode()`?

Comment: Where have you posted the `getZipCode()` method?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it calls the WHOLE list.*" ?? `ArrayList.get(i)` will give you the element at 'i'th location, and there is no debate on it.

Comment: The else is required as per my professor, and it's not causing the problem. If it finds a match, it ignores the else. I could always make it "else if(zips.get(i).getZipCode() != zip)" but that's redundant.

Comment: " it's not causing the problem" Yes it is. You are finding something, storing it, and then throwing that away if the next element doesn't match. You may as well just check the last element of the list, it will have exactly the same output.

Answer (score 4):

You don't stop looping when you find the zip code, so your next iteration through the loop will usually set your return value to null. Change your statement to this:

Edited for your professor:

```
 ZipCode aZip = null;
 for(int i = 0; i < zips.size() && aZip == null; i++) {

    if(zips.get(i).getZipCode() == zip) {
            aZip = zips.get(i);
    }
 }
 if (aZip == null) {
    aZip = new ZipCode(00000);  
    // return new ZipCode(00000); would be better
 }

 return aZip;
```

Comment: I have to return a variable, and the prof gets pissed about returns within loops.

Comment: Then just use `break` keyword after `aZip = zips.get(i);`. `break` means do not loop any further because I have got what I was looking for.

Comment: [Is it bad style to use 'return' to break a for loop in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805258/is-it-bad-style-to-use-return-to-break-a-for-loop-in-java)

Comment: You can also put the break implicitly into the `for` statement declaration: `for(int i = 0; i < zips.size() && aZip.getZipCode() == 0; i++) {`. But returning from inside a loop is fine in my book.

Comment: BUT. That gives me an idea.

Comment: "the prof gets pissed..." To be honest, I'd be more "pissed" about repeatedly calling `zips.get(i)` in the loop, rather than using an enhanced for statement.

Comment: @N.Spock Edited my answer to satisfy your prof, though I don't agree with his POV. ;)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, sorry for being difficult. My class is REALLY new at programming, so he's trying to teach us to be consistent before he lets us run rampant (plus we haven't even learned enhanced for statements yet >///>)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not stoping the iteration when you find the target `ZipCode`, and are assigning `null` to your `aZip` variable in a subsequent iteration.

To solve it, you could use a condition to stop iterating:

```
ZipCode aZip = null;

for (int i = 0; (i < zips.size()) && (aZip == null); i++) {
    if (zips.get(i).getZipCode() == zip) {
        aZip = zips.get(i); // When you set this, aZip will no longer be == null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don’t stop the loop after finding a match, the next iteration’s result will overwrite your match, which is most probably a non-matching item, hence overwrite it with `null`. There are several options:

`break` out:

```
public ZipCode findZip (int zip) {
  ZipCode aZip = null;
  for(int i = 0; i < zips.size(); i++) {
      if(zips.get(i).getZipCode() == zip) {
        aZip = zips.get(i);
        break;
     }
     else
        aZip = null;
  }
  return aZip;
}
```

change the loop condition:

```
public ZipCode findZip (int zip) {
  ZipCode aZip = null;
  for(int i = 0; i < zips.size() && aZip==null; i++) {
      if(zips.get(i).getZipCode() == zip)
        aZip = zips.get(i);
     else
        aZip = null;
  }
  return aZip;
}
```

don’t overwrite:

```
public ZipCode findZip (int zip) {
  ZipCode aZip = null;
  for(int i = 0; i < zips.size(); i++) {
      if(zips.get(i).getZipCode() == zip)
        aZip = zips.get(i);
     else
        continue; // obsolete, but you said, your prof insist on it…
  }
  return aZip;
}
```

---

As a final note, the cleanest solution is to provide a correct [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) method in you `ZipCode` class. If the `ZipCode` class has a proper `equals` implementation, you can implement the method as simple as:

```
public ZipCode findZip (int zip) {
  ZipCode aZip = new ZipCode(zip);
  if(zips.contains(aZip))
    return aZip;
  else
    return null;
}
```

or, even shorter:

```
public ZipCode findZip (int zip) {
  ZipCode aZip = new ZipCode(zip);
  return zips.contains(aZip)? aZip: null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone!

While the other answers do work, here's a different solution that is giving what seems to be correct answers:

```
public ZipCode findZip (int zip) {
      ZipCode aZip = null;
      for(int i = 0; i < zips.size(); i++) {
          if(zips.get(i).getZipCode() == zip) {
            aZip = zips.get(i);
          }
      }
      return aZip;
   }
```

Comment: That's my answer! :P Mine is optimized, though, because it stops iterating when the item is found.

Comment: Sure it does. It was *you* who said the else part was mandated by your prof.

Comment: The null was, so I didn't know another way to put it