# (Java) Iterating through a Array until it hits an null value

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

My problem is that I want a `for loop` to iterate through an array until it hits a `null` value, add an object to the array and then stop iterating through the array.

So for example when I press a key it will add an object to the array but only one object each time I press a key.

Here is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<testArray.length; i++)
{
   if(testArray[i] == null)
   {
      testArray[i] = new object();
   }
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: You may have a problem, but you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Lookup the `break` keyword

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What happens when the array is "full"?

Comment: If the method that contains your loop does not have any code after the loop a `return` is preffered over the `break` statement.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Preferred by who? Why?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle agree with [Micheal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228948/java-iterating-through-a-array-until-it-hits-an-null-value#comment71617512_42228948) - a well placed `break` can make certain algorithms make much more sense. I would say generally you're right, but as with most things there are no absolute rules. Apart from never use `GOTO` - but that's (thankfully) not relevant for Java.

Comment: *"Preferred by who?"* by any skilled programmer. *"Why?"* because `break` (outside of `switch ... case`) is merily a `goto` and is a sign of a flawed design.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle [citation needed]

Comment: I was just wondering is it better to use a break or a Boolean flag

Comment: @TimothyTruckle there is a lot of information and discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805258/is-it-bad-style-to-use-return-to-break-a-for-loop-in-java). There is no absolute answer.

Comment: @AntonH the question is implied. No need to explicitly say the question.

Comment: @Boris the Spider when the array is full no more objects can be added

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to approach this: You can use `break` to exit your loop, or you can use a Boolean flag

Example 1 (break)

```
for(int i=0;i<testArray.length;i++)
{
  if(testArray[i] == null)
  {
   testArray[i] = new object();
   break;
  }
 }
```

Example 2: Boolean flag

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i=0;i<testArray.length && !found;i++)
{
  if(testArray[i] == null)
  {
   testArray[i] = new object();
   found = true;
  }
 }
```

Comment: 3 ways I suppose - 3) place in method an use `return`. Would prefer 3) over 1) over 2). Dislike 2).

Comment: Many thanks, I was just wondering which one would you choose. (which is more commonly accepted)

Comment: My preference is for `break`. For me, it makes the code more legible and the stackframe smaller. On the other hand, `break` is not "clean" - it is effectively like a goto... But then again, I was never that much for "clean" programming - don't shoot me

Comment: @MightyGarlic `break` is my preference too, but if a loop is getting large then I'd separate it out and use return instead. I also dislike #2 - it's a waste of cycles and doesn't add much other than excess complexity. A flag only really works for breaking out of nested loops, but those are one of the only cases where a goto can potentially be applied instead (as you can just jump straight after the loops, instead of breaking out of one, then breaking again).

Comment: @LukeBriggs cheers man, I have been using the flag method for a quite a while, I think I will switch to the `break` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

```
int i = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<testArray.length && testArray[i] != null; i++);

if(i < testArray.length)
{
//now i will represent a position with a null element
testArray[i] = new object();
}
```

Comment: Got to hope that `i < testArray.length` afterwards.

Comment: To be sure you can include testArray[i] = new object() in an if condition ;)

Comment: Also: look carefully, this doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

[break](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) the loop as soon as you find the element....

that is what you are missing:

```
for(int i = 0; i<testArray.length; i++) {
   if(testArray[i] == null) {
      testArray[i] = new object();
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: looking for the doc I forgot to break..  :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) could help? You would just need to listen for the key you are trying to listen     for and check if it's null with

```
for(int i = 0; i < record.length; i++)
        if(record[i] == null) {
            System.out.println(i+1 + " position is null");
        }
```

Feel free to customize this.
Also ControlAltDel's break solution works great.

Answer (score 0):

```java
 Object [] allitems = {"1","2","3","4","5",null,null,null};

 int index= Arrays.asList(allitems).indexOf(null);
 System.out.println("INFO:: The index is:: "+index);
 allitems[index]= new Object();
```

Comment: You didn't completely answer the question since the OP wants to add an object to the array once he encounters a null element in the array.

Answer (score -3):

If your `testArray[]` is an array of `Object`, then you need to use `.equals()` to check for `null`, instead of `==`. Then, you can add `break;` to get out of the `for-loop`.

```
for(int i=0;i<testArray.length;i++)
{
    if(testArray[i].equals(null))
    {
        testArray[i] = new Object();
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an flag to indicate that it is time to get out of the loop

```
private boolean keepLooping = true;
private int i = 0;

while(keepLooping)
{
    if(testArray[i].equals(null))
    {
        testArray[i] = new object();
        keepLooping = false;
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to use `.equals()`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider More than that, if it *is* indeed null you'll get a null pointer exception for trying to dereference it.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider OP might, we don't really know. Depends on what is in that array. `int[] testArray = new int[10]` would not pass a null check, because `int` cannot be null, for instance. We don't have enough information.

Comment: That doesn't really help your case. `int` doesn't have an `equals` method because it's a primitive, so that wouldn't even compile. I'm not sure there's a single reason to call `.equals(null)` because, as @Michael says, you risk a NPE. To add, if it is `null` and you use `==`, you're just say `if(null == null)` which is perfectly fine.

Comment: And another case, if whoever wrote the `.equals()` method didn't check for null for some reason, that could also throw a NPE.